# I want to insert a row on a table and the trigger is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to insert a row on a related table before inserting a row in the first table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION madre_insert_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO curso_madre(nivel,curso)
VALUES('9','9'); 
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO madre' || ' VALUES ($1.*)' USING NEW;

RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigg_madre_insert BEFORE INSERT ON madre FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE madre_insert_trigger();
```

table "madre":

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.Madre(
id_Madre SERIAL,
fk_idcmadre SERIAL,
EDAD INTEGER,
ESTADO_CIVIL INTEGER,
NACIONALIDAD CHAR,
ACTIVIDAD INTEGER,
OCUPACION VARCHAR(50),
CATEGORIA INTEGER,
**CONSTRAINT pk_Madre PRIMARY KEY (id_Madre),
CONSTRAINT fk_idcmadre FOREIGN KEY (fk_idcmadre) REFERENCES PUBLIC.Curso_Madre (id_Curso)**
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your trigger runs `BEFORE` - it must return a non-NULL result, because NULL means `please do not insert anything in the first table`.
Change it to `RETURN NEW;`

Comment: Also **do not** issue the insert statement.. If you do issue that insert you will get a never loop of inserts. The insert in the trigger will cause the trigger to fire, which will in turn cause the trigger to fire, which ....

Comment: @Belayer He is inserting into another table - not the one where the trigger fires. So, unless the other table has a trigger which inserts into the original table - there are no issues.